# Python - Selenium: Scroll divided screen | Linkedin job interface

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, linkedin-api

I would like to find a solution for the next problem: As you can see in the picture there is 2 scrolling interface( rails ). I would like to get each job( for making an automated application process ), which I already done, however at once I can get only 9 elements, hence the screen, therefore I need to scroll down each time I got out the current elements. [linkedin divided interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSdn9.png)

```
job_titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('jobs-search-results__list-item')

for job_title in job_titles:
    print(job_title.text.split('\n')[0])
    driver.implicitly_wait(random_number)
    time.sleep(random_number)

    left_rail = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.jobs-search__left-rail')
    driver.implicitly_wait(random_number)
    time.sleep(random_number)
    left_rail.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

This is the code I am using and it works. I tried with youtube and when I sleect the body or html as the tag then I can scroll( even works on linkedin when the screen is not maximized because then the screen wont be divided.

However once it is divided it doesnt work. I tried to grab every possible element but no success so far. The only element that is intractable is the jobs-search__left-rail class( see on the pic below. However once I pick this item it doesnt scroll.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ncmB.png)

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me when using Chrome the left element that requires scrolling can be controlled the same way as the whole window (also when I open LinkedIn via Safari the page is not divided and the main scroller of the window controls the left side).

So after identifying the list of selenium elements - jobs_list

```
jobs_block= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.jobs-search-results__list')
jobs_list= jobs_block.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.jobs-search-results__list-item')
```

I iterated through the list using .execute_script to reveal new elements

```
n = 0
for i in jobs_list:
    print("__________")
    n+=1
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", jobs_list[n-1])
    print(n, " ",i.text)
```

It worked for me, hope it works for you and others who seek how to solve this. I am only partially satisfied with this solution as it still doesn't cover how to scroll the right side of the screen.

Comment: Hey RZenBridges, thank you for the answer. Since I posted this question I could solve it with the very same solution you posted, however I am grateful for your answer!. I mark it as complete!

Yes I was happy that I could solve it but on the other hand I am not satisfied either why I cant scroll what is scrollable :D